# slowly when recoving from tombstone in wp7

Tags: windows-phone-7, tombstoning

I encountered a problem in my project. It's about tombstone. I found out that it takes a long time to recover, sometimes it can be as long as 5 minutes with no error occuring!

I have never had a problem like that, can anyone tell me why?

Thanks

Comment: How much data did you add to the State? Is there any code you wrote executing? Post it!

Comment: the problem is even though I remove the code that adds data to State, it still proceed like that, so I don't know what to paste...btw, i use mvvmlight.

Comment: If we can't see the code that is executing and we don't know what is put into the state, we can not answer this question. Is it as slow on the emulator as on actual devices?

Comment: check you OnNavigatedTo function. Is it doing something massive which it should not do?

Comment: By the break-point, I found out the much time is waiting & displaying "resuming", when it came to the constructor of app class, everything is back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found where the problem is the code blow, if i remove them, the app works well.

```
DeviceNetworkInformation.ResolveHostNameAsync(
         new System.Net.DnsEndPoint("m.baidu.com", 80),
         new NameResolutionCallback(handle =>
         {
             NetworkInterfaceInfo info = handle.NetworkInterface;
             if (info != null)
             {
                 networkType = GetNetType(info);
             }
             else
                 networkType = NetType.NONE;

         }), null);
```